# VBA Exit Function not working? Success on first call of function, failure on subsequent calls

Tags: vba, excel

I have two functions. The first loops through a range in excel, the second finds a file based on a search string that you provide it with and passes it back to the first.

The second function works by exiting the function when it gets the first match on the search string. However, it's only exiting on the first run through the function, not for any subsequent runs. Instead it jumps to `Next i`.

I have stepped through using F8 and I can see it hit `Exit Function` but it just keeps on running the function regardless.

What have I done wrong?

Function 1:

```
Function GrabQuestionnaireLocations()

    Dim a As Range, b As Range, N As Long, qPath As String

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set a = Range("A2:A" & N)

    For Each b In a.Rows

        qPath = FindFilePath(_ROOT_PATH_, b.Value)

        If Len(qPath) > 0 Then
            Cells(b.Row, "C").Value = qPath
        Else
            Cells(b.Row, "C").Value = "Questionnaire not found"
        End If

        'MsgBox qPath

    Next


End Function
```

Function 2:

```
Function FindFilePath(ByRef FolderPath As String, ByVal v As String) As String

    Dim FileName As String, fullFilePath As String, numFolders As Long, Folders() As String, i As Long
    Dim objFSO As Object, f As Object

    If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then FolderPath = FolderPath & "\"
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.*", vbDirectory)

    While Len(FileName) <> 0

        If Left(FileName, 1) <> "." Then

            fullFilePath = FolderPath & FileName

            If (GetAttr(fullFilePath) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then

                ReDim Preserve Folders(0 To numFolders) As String
                Folders(numFolders) = fullFilePath
                numFolders = numFolders + 1

            Else

                If InStr(fullFilePath, v) > 0 Then                           

                    FindFilePath = fullFilePath                                 
                    Exit Function                                               

                End If       

            End If      

        End If              

        FileName = Dir()

    Wend                        

    For i = 0 To numFolders - 1
        FindFilePath Folders(i), v
    Next i

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're calling the function recursively - calling it from within itself (in the `For i = 0 to numFolders - 1` loop).

If you tell it to exit while it's calling itself from within the For loop it will return to execution in the For loop.

Instead of using `Exit Function` in this position, declare a Boolean variable and set it to True, here. Use `Do While...Loop` instead of the out-dated `While...Wend` construct then you can use `Exit Do` to leave that loop.

Finally, check in the `For` loop whether the Boolean is True and exit that loop. Since that's at the end of the Function, the function will end normally. More like:

```
Function FindFilePath(ByRef FolderPath As String, ByVal v As String) As String
    Dim bMatchFound as Boolean
    Dim FileName As String, fullFilePath As String, numFolders As Long, Folders() As String, i As Long
    Dim objFSO As Object, f As Object

    If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then FolderPath = FolderPath & "\"
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.*", vbDirectory)

    Do While Len(FileName) <> 0    
        If Left(FileName, 1) <> "." Then   
            fullFilePath = FolderPath & FileName   
            If (GetAttr(fullFilePath) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then    
                ReDim Preserve Folders(0 To numFolders) As String
                Folders(numFolders) = fullFilePath
                numFolders = numFolders + 1    
            Else  
                If InStr(fullFilePath, v) > 0 Then                               
                    FindFilePath = fullFilePath                                 
                    bMatchFound = True
                    Exit Do
                End If       
            End If          
        End If              

        FileName = Dir()    
    Loop                        

    For i = 0 To numFolders - 1
        If bMatchFound Then Exit For
        FindFilePath Folders(i), v
    Next i
End Function
```